# Yes/No formula for Calculated Column Type

Tags: sharepoint-online, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

=IF(Fueler,"=Date(YEAR([Fueler Date])+2,MONTH([Fueler Date]),DAY([Fueler Date]))"," ")

The type is yes or no. I would like to know if there is a way that if no is chosen, it would leave the expiration date blank. If the box has a yes checked that it would display a date that 2 years from the Fueler date at the same time. The no displays correctly, but not the yes. It usually gives me syntax errors or just displays the formula as text in the box. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You are very close. Try this:  (remove the extra "=" and quotes)

```
=IF(Fueler,Date(YEAR([Fueler Date])+2,MONTH([Fueler Date]),DAY([Fueler Date]))," ")
```

The only issue with the above is on a leap year. (When Fueler Date = 2/29/16 you will get 3/1/2018)

These are easy to write and test in Excel: http://techtrainingnotes.blogspot.com/2010/08/sharepoint-creating-calculated-column.html

Comment: =IF(Movement Area,Date(YEAR([Fueler Date])+1,MONTH([Movement Area Date]),DAY([Movement Area Date]))," "). This is the formula i'm using for another just to add 1 year from the mark instead of 2 years. It is giving me a syntax error, can't seem to figure out what the problem is. Is there a character limit? Any pointers?

Comment: Your first "Movement Area" does not have square brackets around it.

Comment: SharePoint 2007 and 2010 have a 1024 character limit. 2013 and later are basically unlimited.